# how many different outcomes for the inner product over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

defining the inner product $<u ,v >=\sum_{i=1}^ku_iv_i (mod \ p)$ when $u,v \in GF(p)^k$ ($p$ is a prime).
for any non-zero, fixed $u$ and for every $v$ how can I show that the outcome will be every element in $GF(p)$ exactly $p^{k-1}$ times.

Comment: I am confused; the definition of $\langle u,v\rangle$ has $k$ in the limit of the sum but at the end you write "$n$ is vector's length." Moreover, wouldn't we have $u,v\in\sf{GF}(p)^n$ (i.e. $n$-tuples of elements of $\sf{GF}(p)$?

Comment: your'e right... edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix a vector $u\in GF(p)^n$. Then taking the inner product with $u$ is a linear map $\phi_u:GF(p)^n\to GF(p)$. That is, for vectors $v,w\in GF(p)^n$, $$\langle u, av+w\rangle=\sum u_i(av_i+w_i)=a\sum u_iv_i+\sum_iu_iw_i=a\langle u,v \rangle +\langle u,w \rangle.$$

Now let's show three things for non-zero $u$:

1. The linear map $\phi_u$ is surjective.
2. The kernel $K\subset GF(p)^n$ of this map has $p^{n-1}$ elements. (Hint: Rank-Nullity theorem)
3. Every coset of $K$ in $GF(p)^n$ has exactly $p^{n-1}$ elements.

Conclude your result. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: I thought that the answer will be related to cosets, but I'm having troubles in defining it. coset (by defintion) consists of a group, which has a set of elements and an operator. the group has the closure property. and the mapping of a vector gives scalar. can you put things in order for me?

Comment: @user107761 I see. You can think of the vector space $GF(p)^n$ as a group under addition (Or if you like it better this is the direct sum of $n$ copies of the additive group of $GF(p)$). Linear maps are clearly homomorphisms because they preserve addition.

Comment: so, if I understand you correctly, the operator takes the two vectors,and returns  a vector of size k, which each entry is the inner product?

Comment: @user107761 No, it returns the elementwise sum. Eg $\binom {u_1} {v_1}+\binom {u_2} {v_2}=\binom {u_1+u_2} {v_1+v_2}$.

Comment: I don't follow...